# Bluetooth and delphi , how?

Tags: delphi, bluetooth

I want to send a file to a device (phone) using bluetooth nothing fancy. But i don't know where to start should i find a driver? Maybe one of you guys worked with bluetooth before and can give me a starting point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I hacked some bluetooth support into Indy (because you can only(?) read/write bluetooth via sockets: [Bluetooth Programming with Windows Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) a month ago.

See my post on the indy forum for the code: 
[Indy Bluetooth support](http://forums2.atozed.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=25691)

We use it here for reading a bluetooth barcode scanner (both master and slave mode), with auto connect etc (maybe I need to update the posted code for master support, please let me know if you need it)

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply...i have a question though Do these api work on all bluetooth devices connected to the PC or only on microsoft aproved ones ?

Comment: My code only supports devices with "serial" capabilities, but it could support all bluetooth devices. At least: if you can connect it with Windows, you can use it via sockets.

Comment: Only the MSFT stack uses sockets, so code using Bluetooth sockets will not be of use if the PC has Widcomm, BlueSoleil or Toshiba etc installed. :-,(

Comment: I'm new to delphi, if we use "Bluetooth Programming with Windows Sockets", does the computer that run this program need .net framework?

Comment: Behzad: no, it's just plain win32 api, it has nothing to do with .net

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with it before but I'd start on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362941)

The article explains how to use windows sockets to connect to Bluetooth devices.

There's probably wrappers for these methods. I'll add some more information after I've looked into it