# Bluetooth delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, bluetooth, delphi-2007

I' m new to Delphi and using Delphi 2007, I'm connecting to a Bluetooth printer e and also send data.
Referring to post  [Bluetooth and Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827245/bluetooth-and-delphi-how)  and  [Indy Bluetooth support](http://forums2.atozed.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=25691) , I'm trying to load IdBluetooth.pas in my delphi project and get some errors:

1) ULONG, SYSTEMTIME and all other Windows type are not recognized.

```
sin.port           := ULONG(-1);
```

2) Undeclared identifier FReuseSocket and otUnix at line 107

```
if (FReuseSocket = rsTrue) or ((FReuseSocket = rsOSDependent) and (GOSType = otUnix)) then
```

TdIOHandlerSocket doesn't contain a memeber TdIOhandlerSocket(228 and 311):

```
Socket.ReuseSocket := FReuseSocket;
```

I added JWABluetoothA, JWABtHDef, JWABthSdpDef, JWAWinDLLNames, JWAWindows, JWAws2Bth libraries

How could I fix these errors?

Another question: as well as connecting, if I should send any other data to BT device, what procedure should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - You should probably add the `Windows` unit to the uses clause to make those types available, then.

2 - You're using Delphi 2007, but the date of the article you linked for `Indy Bluetooth Support` is dated in mid-2011. It's most likely it was written for a more recent version of Indy than the one that shipped with Delphi 2007; you'll probably have to either upgrade your Indy version or modify the source of `Bluetooth.pas` to downgrade it to your Indy version.

As far as your "Another question", that would be just that - another (separate) question, since an answer to it now would be meaningless until you can compile `Bluetooth.pas` successfully.